# Why should the relative size of two sets depend on which other sets exist?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Cantor convincingly argued for the proposition that two sets are of the same size exactly when there is some bijective function from one to the other.

However, "functions" are formally defined as sets themselves, and so the relative size of two sets can depend on which other sets (namely, functions between them) exist.

It seems to me that defining a function as a set of ordered pairs (or perhaps actually a triple- the domain, codomain, and then a set of ordered pairs) is a "neat formal trick" as Omar Antolín-Camarena says [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/7822/25028), but "not really how anyone intuitively thinks about a function." Cantor's argument relating size to bijections depends crucially on our intuition.

Is there any way to define functions other than as sets and get around this 'issue', or alternatively formalize an absolute notion of size (something like two sets are equinumerous if a bijective function between them exists in *any* model of set theory)?

Comment: Not everyone agrees that equivalent cardinality implies two sets have the same size.  It turns out that the set of tautologies of propositional logic has the same cardinality as the set of contingencies.  You can form a sequence of tautologies, using Polish notation with C as the material conditional, as follows: (Cpp, CCppCpp, CCCppCppCCppCpp, CCCCppCppCCppCppCCCppCppCCppCpp, ...):=**T-I**  In this sequence you get the next term from the last term by substituting p with Cpp.  Now we'll form a sequence of all the contingencies.  Consider the truth tables of contingencies...

Comment: We can write the values of those contingenices using truth tables as follows (01, 10, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101, 0110, 0111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 00000001, ...) [the next term in the sequence comes as what looks like the number in binary with 2^n digits.. this description is not complete, but it still can get written] := **C**.  Now write a function **G** where **G**: [Cpp]->01, CCppCpp->10, CCCppCppCCppCpp->0001, etc.  Consequently, you can map a subset of the set of all tautologies to the set of all contingencies.  Since...

Comment: You can reverse such a function, and that gives a bijection.  So, the cardinality of the set of contingencies comes as equivalent to the subset **T-1** set of tautologies.  Since a subset of a set always has less than or equal cardinality of one of its supersets, it follows that the cardinality of the set of tautologies comes as greater than or equal to the cardinality of the set of contingencies.  But, I don't think anyone believes the cardinality of the set of tautologies greater than that of contingencies, so I think it reasonable to infer that they have the same cardinality.  However..

Comment: does it make any sense, *any sense at all*, to think that the set of tautologies have the same *size* as the set of contingencies?  I don't think so.  And consequently, I simply do NOT believe that it comes as convincingly argued that two sets *actually* have the same size when they have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generalization you suggest cannot work. Given two infinite sets we can add by forcing a bijection between them. This will result in all infinities collapsing into the same cardinality, rendering this notion completely useless.

Moreover there are models which have non-standard integers. In fact, one can even have more integers in one model than real numbers in another model. So it becomes impossible to even say what is the cardinality of "the integers" since those are not absolute between models of set theory.

But let me offer you an intuitive solution as to why this phenomenon is actually common in mathematics, only when we think about sets it becomes troubling to us. I will also explain why.

**How many cubic roots are there to $2$?** Well, that depends on the mathematical structure we are considering. In the rational numbers the number $2$ doesn't have any number $x$ such that $x^3=2$. On the other hand, in $\Bbb R$ there is exactly one $x$ with this property, whereas in the complex numbers there are *three* such numbers.

So the question becomes dependent on the context in which we are working, and which numbers exist in the "universe of numbers" we might consider at the moment.

But we never really find this issue troubling. Why? Well, we are used to think about the complex numbers as absolute, and the real numbers are absolute, and the rationals are absolute, and so on. This means that there is some "large" universe of "all numbers" (which is how a non-mathematician person usually see this) where everything happens. In fact, asking people what is a number often you will get answers ranging from "Uhm, $0,1,2\ldots$" to "Something signifying physical quantity" to "A complex number".

So we have these canonical models for all the things we think of as numbers. And so there is no issue in stepping up to a larger context when needed. On the other hand set theory has no such canonical model, so we are left with some sort of uncertainty with what sort of objects live in the model we consider at the moment.

The fact that we can switch models causes a lot of tension to people first hearing about it. How can sets be different between models? Well, how can $x^{412341}-2$ have so many different solutions in different contexts? Because context matters.

Equinumerosity depends on the context, much like the other question. It's fine.

Comment: Hmmm... the analogy to the context-sensitivity of questions about numbers is nice. Although, if your post shows why canonical models of numbers are so great, it does raise the question of why set theorists work with a big messy multiverse instead of very nice canonical models (i.e. why $V = L$ is never seriously accepted as an axiom).

Comment: @Sam: $V=L$ gives a very poor universe in a lot of sense. And not much is left to say after that. This is like suggesting that instead of general Banach spaces, everyone work with $\Bbb R^n$. Moreover, even $V=L$ doesn't have a canonical model.

Comment: Nice analogy; +1.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks. I figured it some while ago when I wrote some answer not too-distant from this one about how something is true but not provable (perhaps the continuum hypothesis was the center of the attention at the time). I've been using this analogy ever since.

Comment: "Given two infinite sets we can add by forcing a bijection between them." - I'm intrigued by this assertion; how does it not contradict Cantor's theorem?

Comment: @Sam: It doesn't. We have a universe $V$, and we want to add a bijection between $\Bbb R^V$ and $\Bbb N^V$ (the real numbers of $V$ and the natural numbers of $V$). We add some generic set $G$ (the term generic has a specific meaning, not the "arbitrary" sort of meaning) to the universe from which we can define such bijection. But $\Bbb R^V\neq\Bbb R^{V[G]}$. By adding the bijection we also added *a lot* of new real numbers. So in $V[G]$ we don't have a bijection between the integers and the real numbers of *that* universe.

Comment: So even "being the powerset" of a certain set is not an absolute property?

Comment: @Sam: And why would it be? We add subsets to the universe (e.g. we add a subset of $\Bbb{N\times R}$), then of course the power set should change.

Comment: Thank you. I realize these questions are rather naive; logic is pretty far from the math I have studied, and the exposure I do have is via philosophy (e.g. the work of Alain Badiou).

Comment: @Sam: It's fine. Those are natural questions. Coming to set theory from anywhere but set theory can be confusing. Even coming to it from set theory is confusing at the start.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of what you are proposing was developed in the article

Benci, Vieri; Di Nasso, Mauro, Numerosities of labelled sets: a new way of counting. Adv. Math.  173  (2003),  no. 1, 50–67.

(the notion of numerosity is more "flexible" than that of cardinality).

Jörg D. Brendle's review of

Blass, Andreas; Di Nasso, Mauro; Forti, Marco, Quasi-selective ultrafilters and asymptotic numerosities. Adv. Math.  231  (2012),  no. 3-4, 1462–1486

[here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2964612) specifically compares numerosities and cardinalities.